# How can I check the woocommerce product created/have or not?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I check WooCommerce products are created/have or not? I've added the code and I think also it's not in perfect condition. Actually, I want to check that, has any WooCommerce products. If it has then shown or not then show a notice. How can I do this?

```
$crtp_args = array('post_type' => 'product');
$sk_all_products = new WP_Query( $crtp_args );

while ( $sk_all_products->have_posts() ) : $sk_all_products->the_post();

    global $product;

    if(get_the_ID() == false){

        echo esc_html__('You don\'t have any products. Please add your products.', 'super-men');
    
    }else{

        echo get_the_title();

    }
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: what are the arguments you are passing in `$crtp args`.?

Comment: $crtp args = array('post_type' => 'product');

Comment: then you are getting only products then why you need to check that it's a product or not?

Comment: Because I'm making a plugin that will show some products now when my client add this plugin to her page then he can't see anything also he is confused. That's for I want to make a notice that when don't have any product the show will be a notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if your query has posts or not.

Try out this:

```
$sk_all_products = new WP_Query($crtp_args);

if ($sk_all_products->have_posts()) {
    while ($sk_all_products->have_posts()) : $sk_all_products->the_post();

        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

        echo $product->get_name();
        
    endwhile;
} else {

    echo esc_html__('You don\'t have any products. Please add your products.', 'super-men');

}
```

Comment: You can additionally check the published products by using `post_status` in arguments.

 `$crtp_args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish' );`